# Capital Sigma in bold mathrm

Tags: math-mode, symbols, bold

I want to write capital `\Sigma` in bold `mathrm`. I tried `\boldsymbol{\mathrm{\Sigma}}` but seems like this does not work. Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If not obsolete now (there might be new ways for this), the `bm` package is your friend :) Use as `\bm{\Sigma}`.

Comment: What do you mean it does not seem to work?

Comment: @perusse: Thanks for your comment. \bm{\Sigma} is what I was looking for. Would you mind to include your comment as answer? Thanks

Comment: @Werner: `\boldsymbol{\mathrm{\Sigma}}` produces `.` only.

Comment: @MYaseen208: Not on my system. What packages are you loading?

Comment: @Werner: Thanks for your comment. I do have `multicol`, `amsmath`, `amsbsy`, `amssymb`, `graphicx,epstopdf`, `fontenc`, `fancyvrb`, `relsize`, and `listings`. Do I need to load any special package for this?

Comment: Look at the difference in the formatting of `\Sigma` in the following: `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{amsmath}\begin{document}$\Sigma~\boldmath{\Sigma}~\boldmath{\mathrm{\Sigma}}$\end{document}` If this still produces the incorrect formatting of `\Sigma`, then you need to update your distribution; at least your [AMS LaTeX bundle](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amslatex).

Comment: @Werner Calling `\boldmath` inside a formula is wrong. Your code produces three identical `sigma` characters with the most up-to-date version of TeX Live.

Comment: since you're using `amsmath`, you don't have to load `amsbsy` -- it's loaded automatically by `amsmath`.  also, the default `\Sigma` *is* upright, so `\mathrm` doesn't do anything (unless perhaps you're loading a package that changes the style to sloped, but i didn't see such a package in your list).  finally, `\boldmath` has to be loaded *outside* of math mode, and a warning is emitted if it's found inside.  so the "best" solution (with `amsmath`) is simply `\boldsymbol{\Sigma}`.

Comment: Thanks all for your comments and feedback. I'm pretty happy with `\bm{\Sigma}`. Thanks all again.

Comment: @percusse:I noticed a typo in the request by OP to make your comment an answer, so am resending...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access boldface math symbols with the [bm](http://ctan.org/pkg/bm) package. As usual, it is always beneficiary to go through the manual for some subtle *features*.